# redirect to a page is not working properly in asp .net which is inside sub folder

Tags: asp.net

I have sub folders says X,Y,Z. I'm making menu list dynamically using 'ul', 'li' tags based on user rights. Inside 'li' tag i have 'a href="#"' tag. The tag 'a' filled from database dynamically.

The problem is the tag 'a' has link X/home.aspx. When i click first time this works since it is available. second time 404 page not found error arising. The link become X/X/home.aspx. Obviously this structure is not available. So, how to redirect.

Thanks

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your `href` is continually being added to in this specific scenario (it's a bit of a pitfall in a number of areas, sometimes when using custom controls, etc.), however, you should qualify all of your links from the root by using a prefixed forward-slash (`/`, i.e. `/x/home.aspx`).

But we're not done, ASP.NET can transform these too, in other scenarios, so you might want to use the tilde+forward-slash prefix (`~/`, i.e. `~/x/home.aspx`); this indicates the root of the virtual directory where the site is housed.

In this way, regardless of which level of the sites directories you are in, the links always refer to a *full path*, so to speak.

Comment: Mr.Disappointment. thanks for your time. It doesn't work. Again resource not found. The url is http://localhost/ims/~/X/home.aspx.  Here ims is Main folder and X is sub folder

Answer (score 0):

Your hrefs are relative from the page not from the root of your site...
So do not use "x/home" but use "/x/home".. or use "~/x/home"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are appending the directory. 
If you click for 3rd time you get X/X/X/home.aspx?

Post your code in order to get more help.

Comment: This is my code: <li><a href=" + dtMenu.Rows(index)("ModuleLink")  + ">" + dtMenu.Rows(index)("moduleDesc") + "</a> </li>

Answer (score 0):

Use [Page.ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx)

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/x/home.aspx")
```